# Vertical space between lyrics in MusixTeX

Tags: pdftex, musixtex

How to adjust vertical space between the two lyrics lines? I want them to seperate a little bit. This segment is from the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/musixtex/musixlyr/mxlyrdoc.pdf) of `musixlyr`

```
\begin{music}
\input musixlyr
\large\setlyrstrut
 \resetlyrics
 \setlyrics{Winter1}{Win-ter a-de\rlap{,} a-ber dein Schei-den macht\rlap{,}}
 \setlyrics{Winter2}{schei-den tut weh\rlap,}
 \assignlyrics1{Winter1,Winter2}
 \generalmeter{\meterfrac34}
 \generalsignature2
 \setsongraise1{-2mm}
 \startextract
  \NOtes\qa{ffe}\en\bar
  \NOTesp\hup d\en\rightrepeat
  \assignlyrics1{Winter1}%
  \NOtes\qa{fgh}\en\bar
  \NOtes\qa h\en
  \Notes\beginmel\Ibu0gf1\qb0g\endmel\tqh0f\en
  \NOtes\qa g\en
 \endextract
\end{music}
```

[image]

Update: in case you need a complete source, you can use simply `pdflatex` to compile it

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\input musixlyr
\large\setlyrstrut
 \resetlyrics
 \setlyrics{Winter1}{Win-ter a-de\rlap{,} a-ber dein Schei-den macht\rlap{,}}
 \setlyrics{Winter2}{schei-den tut weh\rlap,}
 \assignlyrics1{Winter1,Winter2}
 \generalmeter{\meterfrac34}
 \generalsignature2
 \setsongraise1{-2mm}
 \startextract
  \NOtes\qa{ffe}\en\bar
  \NOTesp\hup d\en
 \endextract    
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You will increase your chances of getting a timely and good answer by providing us with a complete example, which starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @marmot I updated the complete example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapting code from the [musictex manual](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/musixtex/doc/musixdoc.pdf), you can set the `\lyrstrutbox` instead of using `\setlyrstrut`.  Here is an exaggerated version:

```
\setbox\lyrstrutbox=\vbox to 4.3\Interligne{}
```

In your example this gives:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
  \input musixlyr
  \setbox\lyrstrutbox=\vbox to 4.3\Interligne{}
  \resetlyrics
  \setlyrics{Winter1}{Win-ter a-de\rlap{,} a-ber dein Schei-den macht\rlap{,}}
  \setlyrics{Winter2}{schei-den tut weh\rlap,}
  \assignlyrics1{Winter1,Winter2}
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac34}
  \generalsignature2
  \setsongraise1{-2mm}
  \startextract
  \NOtes\qa{ffe}\en\bar
  \NOTesp\hup d\en
 \endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```