# Vertical space inside assignlyrics musixlyr

Tags: musixtex, musixlyr

It is needed to add vertical space between lyrics of a same assignlyrics command. The basic code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[
border={-1.7cm % Izquierda
    +5pt % Abajo
    -2.3cm % Derecha
    +5pt % Arriba
},landscape,a1paper,10pt,class=scrartcl]{standalone}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
  \resetlyrics
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\setlyrics{triadaC1}{I II III IV V VI VII I}% added for hand indication
\setlyrics{triadaC2}{IM IIm IIIm IVM VM VIm VIIdim IM}%
\setlyrics{triadaC3}{I ii iii IV V vi vii\textsuperscript{o} I}%
\setsongraise1{-6mm}
\staffbotmarg3\Interligne % set verticle space in one staff score
%\setsongraise2{-12mm}
\setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
\nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
\nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
\startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
\A\assignlyrics1{triadaC1,triadaC2,triadaC3}%
\NOTEs\zchar{-9.2}{\hspace*{-1.7cm}\color{red-undar}\A Tradicional}\zchar{-13.7}{\hspace*{-1.7cm}\color{red-undar}\A Anglosajon}\zchar{-18.3}{\hspace*{-1.7cm}\color{red-undar}\A Alternativo}\hsk\zchar{13}{C}\zwh{ce}\wh{g}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{Dm}\zwh{df}\wh{h}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{Em}\zwh{eg}\wh{i}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{F}\zwh{fh}\wh{j}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{G}\zwh{gi}\wh{k}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{Am}\zwh{hj}\wh{l}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{B\textsuperscript{o}}\zwh{ik}\wh{m}\en%\bar
\setdoubleBAR
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{C}\zwh{jl}\wh{n}\en
\nolyr
\lyricsoff
\endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Vertical space between lyrics in MusixTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481141/316068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just por beginners, as it has been solved in a duplicated post [related link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481141/316068); the solutions is as follow:

```
\documentclass[
border={-1.7cm % Izquierda
    +10pt % Abajo
    -2.3cm % Derecha
    +5pt % Arriba
},landscape,a1paper,10pt,class=scrartcl]{standalone}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
  \resetlyrics
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\setlyrics{triadaC1}{I II III IV V VI VII I}% added for hand indication
\setlyrics{triadaC1clon}{\empty{} \empty{} \empty{} \empty{} \empty{} \textbf{} \empty{} \empty{}}% added for hand indication
\setlyrics{triadaC2}{IM IIm IIIm IVM VM VIm VIIdim IM}%
\setlyrics{triadaC2clon}{\empty{} \empty{} \empty{} \empty{} \empty{} \textbf{} \empty{} \empty{}}% added for hand indication
\setlyrics{triadaC3}{I ii iii IV V vi vii\textsuperscript{o} I}%
\setsongraise1{-9mm}
\staffbotmarg3\Interligne % set verticle space in one staff score
%\setsongraise2{-12mm}
\setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
\nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
\nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
\startextract %inicia el fragmento musical
\A\assignlyrics1{triadaC1,triadaC1clon,triadaC2,triadaC2clon,triadaC3}%
\NOTEs\zchar{-8.7}{\hspace*{-1.7cm}\color{red-undar}\A Tradicional}\zchar{-17.2}{\hspace*{-1.7cm}\color{red-undar}\A Anglosajon}\zchar{-26.0}{\hspace*{-1.7cm}\color{red-undar}\A Alternativo}\hsk\zchar{13}{C}\zwh{ce}\wh{g}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{Dm}\zwh{df}\wh{h}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{Em}\zwh{eg}\wh{i}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{F}\zwh{fh}\wh{j}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{G}\zwh{gi}\wh{k}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{Am}\zwh{hj}\wh{l}\en%\bar
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{B\textsuperscript{o}}\zwh{ik}\wh{m}\en%\bar
\setdoubleBAR
\NOTEs\hsk\zchar{13}{C}\zwh{jl}\wh{n}\en
\nolyr
\lyricsoff
\endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}
\end{document}
```